# Is there any Ebay APi available for listing an item, inventory update Etc PHP

Tags: php, ebay-api

Is there any ebay api available for listing an item, inventory update. Import orders from ebay etc. Can you provide me the sample code in php

Answer (score 1):

Try this : http://developer.ebay.com/common/api/

> Using the API, you can create programs that:
>
> - Submit items for listing on eBay
> - Get the current list of eBay categories
> - View information about items listed on eBay
> - Get high bidder information for items you are selling
> - Retrieve lists of items a particular user is currently selling through eBay
> - Retrieve lists of items a particular user has bid on
> - Display eBay listings on other sites
> - Leave feedback about other users at the conclusion of a commerce transaction

<strike>[For PHP Accelerator Toolkit for eBay see here](https://www.x.com/developers/ebay/php-accelerator-toolkit-ebay-trading-api-edition)</strike> [The toolkit is no longer available, see here](http://go.developer.ebay.com/developers/ebay/php-accelerator-toolkit-ebay-shopping-api-edition)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But i need the php code for it. Is that API's available.

Comment: @user1310210 See the link at the bottom of my answer

Comment: Do you have the source code in php ? Kindly provide the link ?

Comment: @ManseUK link is broken

Comment: that means PHP SDK has removed so we cannot find any PHP scripts

Comment: @RakeshShetty there are loads of examples in the Developer Zone [here](http://go.developer.ebay.com/developers/ebay/php-perl-and-python-developer-center) and [here](http://go.developer.ebay.com/developers/ebay/documentation-tools/code-samples) are just 2 examples

Comment: One of good php solution is there with example how to list/revise item —https://github.com/davidtsadler/ebay-sdk-examples